# Transforming polygones with 90 degree edges by deleting the vertices

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a lot of polygons of buildings with small balkonies and edges and *zig-zags* (see the figure below):

[image].

I want to delete vertices which does not satisfy a criterion like distance between vertices bigger than 3 meters.

Is there any script or tool for doing that?

I am familiar with writing python codes but I don't know how  can I write a script in QGIS. How can I find the names of variables, etc.?

Is there any tutorial for doing it in QGIS?

Comment: Have you check [convex hull](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) for example?

Comment: I do not think that it works. I found the convex hull in SAGA tools. As I understood, I have to tansform my polygones to point data and then use the tool. But it tooks the points of all of buildings together.

Comment: QGIS → Vector → Geoprocessing tools → Convex hull, and then: Field: selected your record id; Method: Create convex hulls based on field. This will create a convex hull for each of your polygons.